# PHP: setting content length of MIME message

Tags: php, mime

I have to build an API in php that returns a request to Java coder.
This is what I have done.

```
header("MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol);
header("Connection: Keep-Alive".$eol);
header("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate".$eol);
header("Host: host".$eol.$eol);
header("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary".$eol);
echo $res;
```

So, there is main headers and `$res` variable which is a bdy of response.
I form it this way.

```
$eol="\r\n";
$BOUNDARY = "boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary"; 
$res="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
$res .= "Content-Type: application/json".$eol;
ob_start();
print_r($json);
$result = ob_get_clean();
$data .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($result).$eol.$eol;
$res.=$result;
$res.=$eol.$eol;
$res.="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
ob_start();
readfile('/var/www/9292/inputPhoto.jpg');
$result = ob_get_clean();
$res.="Content-Type: image/jpeg".$eol;
$imageLength=strlen($result)+6;
//I add +6 because of 3 $eol
$res.=$eol;
$res.=$result;
$res.=$eol.$eol;
$res.="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
$res .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".$eol;
ob_start();
readfile('/var/www/9292/1.etmpl');
$result = ob_get_clean();   
$vectorLength=strlen($result)+6;
$res .= "Content-Length: ".$vectorLength.$eol;
$res.=$eol;
$res.=$result;
$res .= $eol.$eol;
$res .= "--".$BOUNDARY."--".$eol;
```

Here is output that Java coder received.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 12:30:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 99.999.999.99:99
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=--boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary

2d66
--boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary
Content-Type: application/json
{JSON That I can't show here}

--boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 1917

����JFIF``��C
*��^I _|�rd�HE�8�H X}�)o�d�����ƭ�2I�u�I P�$��
Content of picture
----1429705906426boundary--


--boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 9222

H67a831e8-5f0
Content of vector
--boundary...//not sure if I can show boundary
```

Rather strange that I don't have content length of JSON, however I set it as you can see in code. Also I can see some strange `2d66` before first boundary.
Otherwise output is fine, Java coder can receive image, vector and json.
But also he receives a mistake:

```
Unexpected end of headers detected. Higher level boundary detected or EOF reached.
```

As I understand content-length is wrong somewhere.Anyone experienced with MIME can show me mistake?

Comment: Why `java` is tagged to this question?

Comment: Ok, I removed it. I was not sure if it can affect somehow.